# Cakephp 2.5.4: Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: cakephp

I want to show error for database in cakephp. How can I display a message of "sql error" to the users. This is my code. In this code, I am getting Database Error. But I want to show proper message to the user instead of database error.

```
public function edit_mothertongue(){    
    $motherTongue=array();
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        foreach ($this->request->data as $key => $value) {
        $motherTongue[$key]=$value;
        }
        if(!empty($motherTongue)){
            App::import('Model','MotherTongue');
            $this->MotherTongue=new MotherTongue();
            try{
                if($this->MotherTongue->save($motherTongue)){
                    echo "Record saved";
                }else{
                    echo "Record not saved";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage(); // I want to display error message of sql.
            }
        }       
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to display information, you need to use a view. To pass information from the controller to the view use the [set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::set) method.

```
$this->set('errormsg', $e->getMessage());
```

Then use `$errormsg` in your view.

Comment: If I want to display error message through ajax, then what should I do? Please answer to this question as well, i will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AJAX you can set it like this:

```
        $this->set('_serialize', array('errormsg'));
```

If you are looking for an output in JSON

However using AJAX is out of scope of this question.